# Block loading stuck on 1 year 13 weeks

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

My parent's have Windows Vista and recently we had a power outage and Bitcoin started from beginning loading blocks however for a week now it doesn't go below 1 year 13 months? As an inexperienced Bitcoiner, I could use some advice. Please help if you can. Thank you.Please make it simple as I'm new and don't understand all the Bitcoin terminology.
David

Comment: Are you using the standard Bitcoin Core client?  What version?

Comment: I'm using v0.11.0 version. It's been stuck there since yesterday and tells me there are no connections.